# Access photos on iphone via script

Tags: c#

How to access iPhone with c# in visual studio console app? The phone appears in the file explorer but I do not know how to get it in code. After what I've read, it is very complicated.

I am not a dev but I can read and try lots of stuff.

I am on windows 10.

Comment: Are you running Windows? If so you probably need to map the DCIM folder to a drive letter in Windows (if it isn't mounted on one already). If it's Mac then you need to find what path the DCIM folder was mounted to on the filesystem

Comment: @ADyson "drive-letter mapping" only applies to SMB shares. When you attach a digital camera (or smartphone, including iPhone) it uses PTP instead of USB Mass Storage, which Windows exposes as a shell folder that can only be accessed via the Shell Namespace API and not the Filesystem API (i.e. you cannot `CreateFile` to a PTP device).

Comment: @Dai thanks for that, not something I was aware of having never tried to work with a device like that through code. Hopefully that info is useful to the OP too!

Comment: @ADyson That said, there are products available like MTPDrive which **do** make PTP/MTP devices available through the filesystem: https://www.mtpdrive.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a usefull library to solve your problem called
[MediaDevices](https://github.com/Bassman2/MediaDevices) from the GitHub user [Basman2](https://github.com/Bassman2). You can find this library also on the [NuGet Store](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaDevices/).

For the examples you can download the [GitHub](https://github.com/Bassman2/MediaDevices) repo and test the implemented features.
The library has functionalities to download files from your device or upload them.

With this tool you can also display your files like in the link below.

[Screenshot from the file section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRFwy.png)

I hope this can fix your problem.

Comment: Great library. Worked like charm with iPhone in a project to copy photos.